# Removing smart card login from my Mac

Tags: macos, security, keychain, smart-card

I've seen a lot of questions about adding a smart card login to a Mac, but my problem is the opposite.

I have a company smart card that I use on my personal computer sometimes for checking webmail and such. However, at some point I must have done some Keychain stuff with it inserted into the USB reader, because ever since it requires me to insert the smart card and enter its pin in order to unlock my lock screen or to approve software installs and updates.

**Note:** I **can** Switch Users and login normally to those accounts.

I don't want to mess up my keychain, so I'm hoping someone can tell me what I need to do to bring things back to normal so I can manage my personal computer with just my personal credentials.

Answer (score 6):

## Use `sc_auth unpair …`

This worked for me:

```
/usr/sbin/sc_auth unpair -u [username]
```

The `sc_auth` command…

> [`sc_auth`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/sc_auth/) configures a local user account to permit authentication using a supported smart card.  Authentication is via asymmetric key (also known as public-key) encryption.  `sc_auth` works with signing keys, but not encryption keys.

…with the option `unpair`:

> `unpair`   Remove association with a user and keychain. If no specific hash is provided, all associations with a user are removed.

Comment: thanks, I had the same issue as the original question and this resolved it

Comment: You can also stop the notification coming up each time you plug in the token by going to System Preferences - Notifications - Smartcard ... turn it off

Comment: Thanks - this removed my pesky Yubikey PIV auth.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative answer to the one above, you can use

```
sc_auth list
```

to get the current list of hashes linked to your account.

Once you have the hash(es) that you want to remove, use

```
sc_auth unpair -h [hash]
```

to unlink the smart card from your account.