# Can I make my Mac have two passwords for one account?

Tags: mac, password

Is there any way I can get my login to accept two different passwords?

Comment: I know if no way to do this, with *anything*

Comment: Why? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You can set two different admin accounts (with two different passwords), such that if you forget the password for one account you can login to the other and change it. 

You can also join two accounts using the shell group command and reset permissions (which is really complicated). 

There is other ways, but I'd think more laterally about your objectives.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. There is no way to specify this in macOS. I've never seen this ability in any operating system I've used in 35+ years in the profession.

You can [set a firmware password](https://www.imore.com/how-set-your-macs-firmware-password-and-why-you-shouldnt) on your Mac, adding an extra level of security before a user login, but it is not recommended.

Comment: Why is a firmware password "not recommended," and by whom? For a laptop, presumably more subject to theft than a desktop, protecting against the easy boot-from-a-USB-stick login password bypass seems to me a reasonable precaution,

Comment: Just do not forget your firmware password.

Comment: "Not recommended" in that if you forget the Firmware password, you're locked out of your system. Only Apple can get past the Firmware password for you, but you must provide acceptable proof of ownership, which can be hard to prove if you're not the original owner. Enrolling your Mac in AppleCare is the best way to prove ownership, even if it has lapsed. If you do choose a Firmware password, _write it down_ and store it safely somewhere. If you choose to sell or give your Mac as a gift, make sure to disable the FW password beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can somehow using a Signing Stick or Smart Card…

You set a user account with it's password and you associate / pair that user with « **sc_auth** » in order to use « **smart card** » along with it's PIN…

That can be somehow « handy » for a small business to login as a defined user (eg. if sick) whilst making sure the user doesn't have to provide it's password… Therefore you have to either force the person to use a « smart card » to login everyday or alternatively setup one for the user account as a bypass.

Check also [Removing smart card login from my Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/290253/removing-smart-card-login-from-my-mac)

Environnement with more users should consider not having to login as the user but use delegate accesses and simplify user login experience with solutions such as https://jumpcloud.com/blog/mac-system-login-microsoft-365-password or https://www.jamf.com …